# Why is Monero GUI stuck when it says it's syncing?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, synchronization

Save a newbie of Monero and Linux.  I'm running Ubuntu and Monero 'Wolfram Warptangent' (v0.10.3.1-release).  Network status is green and says synchronizing, but blocks remaining moves up 1 every so often.

Daemon Log says the following:

2017-06-15 11:45:04.262     7f249e936740    INFO    global  contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:145   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,stacktrace:INFO
Height: 1317604/1333187 (98.8%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash 72.03 MH/s, v5, up to date, 8(out)+0(in) connections, uptime 0d 0h 48m 54s

Any suggestions?

Comment: I forgot to add.  It has spent three days on this block.  I've tried restarting it, which does nothing.

Comment: Are you stuck on a certain block? Or is it just fetching new blocks very slowly?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a certain block.  I haven't seen it move forward.

Comment: Could you add this as daemon startup flag and restart the GUI? Make sure that the daemon is closed as well.

`--block-sync-size 20`

The daemon startup flag box is located on the Settings page of the GUI.

Comment: Thanks for your interest in my problem dEBRUYNE.  When I restart the GUI, it deletes the startup flag.  I tried stopping and starting the daemon with the flag, and as of now it seems to be doing the same thing.  (Synchronizing, but the blocks remaing ticks backward by one every so often.)  Any other ideas?  It's a six year old laptop.  If no solution is found I'm thinking I'll install Linux Mint and try again.

Comment: Update:  Around 20 minutes since I added the flag, blocks remaining is ticking downward again.  So, as of now you seem to have solved the problem.  I'll keep you posted.

Comment: That's good to hear. Hopefully it fully resolved your issue.

Comment: Wow, completely solved my problem.  I'm very excited to start using Monero and storing it properly.  Add your answer and I'll promote it.  (Speculate on why this worked if you like.)  Thanks dEBRUYNE!

Comment: I've written a full guide, which can be found [here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/4462/my-blockchain-is-stuck-how-do-i-unstuck-it). I'll add the guide as answer. It could be that your PC / laptop simply was unable to handle batches of 200 blocks, whereas it is perfectly able to handle batches of 20 blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was resolved by simply adding `--block-sync-size 20` as daemon startup flag. You can do this on the Settings page of the GUI. In addition, a full guide to getting your blockchain "unstuck" can be found [here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/4462/my-blockchain-is-stuck-how-do-i-unstuck-it).